# Is "five-yearly" an acceptable usage of an adverb of manner in British English?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, adverbs, headline-english

[Today's BBC News web page](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/health-19992538) has this headline:

> New era of **five-yearly** doctor checks starts

There's a word that means "five-yearly": *[quinquennial](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quinquennial)*. It's probably too long for headline writers and too difficult for most readers, so I understand why it wasn't used, but shouldn't it have been *five-year* instead?

> New era of **five-year** doctor checks starts

Comment: Huh. I thought "five-yearly" meant "five a year", but reading the article makes it clear that it's "once every five years". Am I the only one who made this error?

Comment: No, that was my initial misunderstanding too.

Comment: Murphy's Law for writers is Whatever can be misunderstood will be. Rewrite: ***New Era: Doctors checked every five years.*** Same number of characters.

Comment: I make **five yearly** visits to my dentist, but only **five-yearly** visits to my cardiologist. The latter is, to me, quite clear thanks to the use of the hyphen. I certainly find such punctuated usage easier to understand than, say, words like _biweekly_ and _bimonthly_.

Comment: I read *five-yearly checks* as "checks happening once every five years", and *five-year checks* as "checks that are five years long each". Needless to say, I prefer the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just my opinion, but it is a poorly written headline. It really makes it sound like you now need to visit the doctor five times per year instead of a doctor being appraised once every five years. I'm from Canada by the way. When I looked at it my first thought was five per year, but then my logical brain took over and said that the writer did a bad job right after reading it. And a check of the article confirms this. :)

Answer (score 1):

A "five-year doctor check" would be one lasting five years.  It can't help but bring to mind Star Trek's "five-year mission".   :)

I know you were asking about British usage, but for what it's worth - "five-yearly" would probably be understood (albeit with some strange looks) in American English.  An American paper would probably avoid the issue by making the headline more generic:  "New Era of Doctor Visits Begins".

Comment: Good points. My initial understanding was "five checks per year".

Comment: _Yearly_ (like _leisurely_; _hourly_) has a dual existence, of course, as an adverb and an adjective: _He visits the doctor yearly. / He makes yearly visits to the doctor_. It would seem to make sense that the compound five-yearly would also, but _He visits the doctor five-yearly_ sounds distinctly off. coleopterist and Lynn explain the three different usages (five yearly...; five-yearly...; five-year...) clearly.

Answer (score 0):

*Quinquennial* seems preferable to me, but if not using that word, how about *fifth-yearly* for a repeating period of five-year intervals?